# Embedding a Mobile Site on a Web Page without an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, responsive-design, media-queries

My goal is to embed two versions of the same site (mobile and tablet) on the same page.  Originally, this was done within an iFrame but I started working with a CMS no longer handles exporting to iFrames well.

I've looked into Java Script solutions such Element Queries, but those solutions seem tied to specific elements (i.e. `header[min-width~="500px"]`)

I'm looking for a solution that will fire a series of `@media screen and (min-width: XXXpx)` with respect to the container I'm embedding the site in.

I've also tried a solution loading the site into a div with jQuery - but the embedded site's 'width' is still relative to the browser and not the container.

Much thanks to any guidance.

Comment: Ajax but clone the response, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35466491/2813224) I know the score is -1, but if you look at the demo, you'll see it works great. In your case, you'll just need the firs file `xhr.html` and then target the page you want to copy. If this works for you then upvote the post there. If you have any questions (you probably will, it can be confusing), don't hesitate to ask.